# Multiple files with the same name and a tilde are written while editing a file with gvim

Tags: filesystems, gvim, tilde

I am under fedora 29. I edit my files with gvim and since a few days, one of them appears multiple times, renamed with an additional letter and tilde. The directory looks like this :

```
sf1.pdf   sf1.tec~  sf1.tef~  sf1.tei~  sf1.tel~  sf1.teo~  sf1.ter~  sf1.teu~  sf1.tex   sf1.tez~  sf1.nav  sf1.snm   sf1.ted~  sf1.teg~  sf1.tej~  sf1.tem~  sf1.tep~  sf1.tes~  sf1.tev~  sf1.tex~  sf1.toc sf1.aux  sf1.out  sf1.teb~  sf1.tee~  sf1.teh~  sf1.tek~  sf1.ten~  sf1.teq~  sf1.tet~  sf1.tew~  sf1.tey~
```

Apparently the whole alphabet is doing something here, but I really don't udnerstand what's going on (I don't even know what context to provide for more details !). If anyone has a clue as to what's going on and how this could be stopped...

Thanks a lot !

Marc

Comment: These look like they might be backup files, I've not seen them alphabetized like that though.  One is common, not twenty six.  See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607435/why-does-vim-save-files-with-a-extension

Comment: Then again if these were backup files, it would take a reasonably complex configuration to enable so many.  See here http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backupext'

Comment: Thanks for your answer Philip ! I have no particular configuration regarding back-up, so just the filename with a dot in front of it as is normal with vim... I really don't understand what is going on ! I never saw such a thing happen, before two or three days ago.